# How can I set a value of a user defined type using reflection?

Tags: go

I have a type

```
type SpecialString *string
```

I have two reflect values, `aVal` and `bVal` (just to be clear `aVal` and `bVal` are of type `reflect.Value`) where

```
aVal.Type() // *SpecialString
bVal.Type() // *string
```

In regular code I can create `c`, a pointer to a special string like so:

```
a := "foo"
b := SpecialString(&a)
c := &b
```

How can I achieve the same using reflection?

```
aval.Set(bVal) // does not work: "reflect.Set: value of type *string is not assignable to type *SpecialString"
```

Comment: The snippet with a, b, c does not compile.

Comment: My bad, I meant `type SpecialString *string`, edited now.

Comment: The underlying type of `*SpecialString` is `**string`.  A `*string` is not assignable to a `**string`.  Show your reflect code.  See https://play.golang.org/p/8h9tz3xM8KV for a working example of assigning `*string` to `SpecialString`.

Comment: @Alex: Don't define pointer types like `SpecialString *string`. Either use `SpecialString string`, or if you are trying to enforce having a pointer, us a struct with a single pointer field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the types and pay attention to what you can and cannot set. Something like:

```
type SpecialString string
var s string = "source regular string"
var ss SpecialString
// Get the reflect.Value of the thing &ss pointing at.
ssv := reflect.ValueOf(&ss).Elem() 
// You need to convert string to SpecialString explicitly
ssv.Set(reflect.ValueOf(s).Convert(ssv.Type())) 
fmt.Printf("ss = %T %+#v\n", ss, ss)
```

https://play.golang.org/p/OtFuS5bAaax

Comment: OP changed the type to `type SpecialString *string` while you are answering.

Comment: @ThunderCat, that doesn't really matter. The principle stays the same: https://play.golang.org/p/MBRP0ddK7kt

Comment: Because a  `*string` is assignable to a `SpecialString`, explicit conversion is not required.